# 'int' object is not callable error python

Tags: python, int

Hey guys so I am getting this "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" error when I run this code, I did some research and I think it's something with my variable naming? Could someone please explain to me what is wrong?

```
class account(object):
    def set(self, bal):
        self.balance = bal
    def balance(self):
        return balance
```

Here is my example run:

```
>>> a = account()
>>> a.set(50)
>>> a.balance()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    a.balance()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error pointing to?

Answer (score 13):

You are masking your method `balance` with a instance attribute `balance`. Rename one or the other. You could rename the instance attribute by pre-pending it with an underscore for example:

```
def set(self, bal):
    self._balance = bal

def balance(self):
    return self._balance
```

Attributes on the instance trump those on the class (except for data descriptors; think `property`s). From the [Class definitions documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions):

> Variables defined in the class definition are class attributes; they are shared by instances. Instance attributes can be set in a method with `self.name = value`. Both class and instance attributes are accessible through the notation “`self.name`”, and an instance attribute hides a class attribute with the same name when accessed in this way.