# Error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" in a for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out some values according to a sequence rule n(n+1)/2 from another list, I have so far:

```
for i in range(0,5):
 print LHS[(i(i+1))/2]
```

Why should this not work but `print LHS[i]` be fine?

However this is raising the error in the title. I do not understand why this would not work in Python.

If anybody could help I would be very grateful!!

Comment: possible duplicate of ['int' object is not callable error python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841910/int-object-is-not-callable-error-python)

Comment: @Marcin: not the best dupe target; there the OP masked a method with a instance attribute, which was surprising for different reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot an operator here:

```
i(i+1)
```

Python interprets that as a call expression; `i` must be a callable, passing in `i+1` as the single argument. Since `i` is an integer instead, which is not callable, you get an exception.

Perhaps you meant:

```
i * (i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call "i" as a function i(i+1)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you meant :
    i*(i+1)
?